# SQL insert into error VB.NET

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

running a vb application with the following code. I keep getting an error on my 'INSERT INTO' sql query, can anyone see what im doing wrong? This is the error - Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

```
 connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\Users\Dave\Documents\joblist.mdb;"

            connection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connetionString)


            Sql = "INSERT INTO jobList (StaffID, staffName, staffLastName, note, fault, section, techID, jobcomplete) VALUES ('" & staffid & "','" & staffFN & "','" & staffLN & "','" & staffNotes & "','" & staffFault & "', '" & staffSection & "', '" & techId & "','" & ava & "')"
            connection.Open()
            oledbAdapter.UpdateCommand = connection.CreateCommand
            oledbAdapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = Sql
            oledbAdapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            connection.Close()
            Me.JobListTableAdapter.Fill(Me.JoblistDataSet2.jobList)
```

Comment: Is `StaffID` is autoincremental column??

Comment: INSERT INTO Persons
VALUES (4,'Nilsen', 'Johan', 'Bakken 2', 'Stavanger')
this is the syntax for insert in sql.change accordingly and try.

Comment: staffid is a autoinc column, i reference it from another form and insert it into this sql. the error im getting is - Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: And now try entering an apostrophe into any of your fields and watch it melt, then [read this](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html). There's no excuse for using string concatenation in SQL commands any more, it's just begging to be exploited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Note` and `Section` are [reserved words in Jet SQL](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266/en-us)
You need to encapsulate them with square brackets

```
Sql = "INSERT INTO jobList (StaffID, staffName, staffLastName, [note], fault, " +
      "[section], techID, jobcomplete) VALUES (......)"
```

This is the source of you syntax error, but .....
aside from that, you have many problems here:

- As pointed out by Tim Schmeiter, you use the update command instead of
  insert command.
- you concatenate input text from your user to form an sql string. This
  leads to sql injection attacks and problems in correct parsing of text
  (apostrophes, invalid dates, invalid numbers, etc)
- `staffID` and `techID` seems to be numeric fields in the database, but
  you put their values inside single quotes like strings. If they are
  numerics you will get another possible error there.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you should use the [`InsertCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337632.aspx) instead of the [`UpdateCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.updatecommand.aspx) property since you are inserting.

```
oledbAdapter.InsertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO jobList (StaffID, staffName, ....
```

Note that you're open for SQL-Injection and should use [`Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead. You should also use [`Using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) statement to ensure that the connection gets closed even on error.